# Why can't view the documentation of addEventListener method in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I want to use the View External Documentation function to view the documentation of the `addEventListener` method, but there is no response at all, and it is the same with Quick Definition.

This is obviously a very common method, why can't view the document?

How to quickly view the document in this case?

I didn't find the answer in the [official document](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/viewing-external-documentation.html).

[image]

Comment: It looks like IDE does not know what type `item` parameter is. Try specifying it via JSDoc -- any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check 'Show the documentation popup ...' in File > Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion

[image]

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Q is my shortcut key. I already pressed it.

Comment: In my case it's Shift-F1 and it works (opens mozilla mdn in browser, but not everything is found). My answer concerns the documentation popup for code completion (can also be activated with a shortcut key, here it's Ctrl-Shift-F1), I suppose that's not wat you meant.

Comment: @Kooilnc I thought all the content could be found. If this is not the case, then there will be no doubt. Thank you for your answer.